# Using global function (nunjucks) in Markdown post

Tags: markdown, nunjucks, hexo

I'm trying to use a Nunjucks function I've created on a Markdown post in Hexo, but I can't make it work.

I'm using `hexo-renderer-njcks` and `hexo-renderer-marked` and I have added a global function like this:

```
hexo.extend.filter.register('before_render:nunjucks', function SplitFilter (env) {
    env.addGlobal('render_img_tag', function (path) {
        return '<img src="' + path + '" />';
    })
})
```

When I check the `env.globals`, the function is correclty present, but when I try to generate the files, I get the following error:

```
Nunjucks Error:  [Line 3, Column 12] Error: Unable to call `render_img_tag`, which is undefined or falsey
    =====             Context Dump Ends            =====
    at formatNunjucksError (/home/user/www/dsite.com/node_modules/hexo/lib/extend/tag.js:102:13)
    at Promise.fromCallback.catch.err (/home/user/www/dsite.com/node_modules/hexo/lib/extend/tag.js:124:34)
    at tryCatcher (/home/user/www/dsite.com/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/user/www/dsite.com/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:517:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/home/user/www/dsite.com/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:574:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/user/www/dsite.com/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:619:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/home/user/www/dsite.com/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:695:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (/home/user/www/dsite.com/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
    at _drainQueue (/home/user/www/dsite.com/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (/home/user/www/dsite.com/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:147:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/home/user/www/dsite.com/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:632:19)
```

How can I do it?

(Note: I can change the modules if necessary).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is a hack or a working solution but ... well ... it works!

On your "script.js" file in your theme, you can do the following to add global functions:

```
hexo.extend.tag.env.addGlobal('render_img_tag', function (path) {
    return '<img src="' + path + '" />';
})
```